# How to check the registers value of the network card on ARM Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, driver

On our device, we observed that the IPv6 NS packet with multicast address of Layer2 were droped. The tcpdump cannot capture these packet so I guess the packets were dropped by the network card driver(correct me if I am wrong).

To verify this, I want to write a module to check the value of some registers in the network card. Since it is not possible for me to recompile the original driver I need a separate module to finish this job.

Is it possible to do that? How?

Comment: Why can't you recompile the driver? And how do you expect to fix the bug, even if you do find it, if you can't recompile the driver?

Comment: because I just want to confirm and locate the bug in current stage

Answer (score 1):

You can recompile the driver, adding `printk` with whatever it is you want to see.

If you are developing for an ARM target, it is possible you are using the [Embedded Linux Dev Kit (ELDK)](http://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/ELDK), so you could look in the kernel source tree for the driver,  modify it, and rebuild the kernel.  Or you could remove the resident driver and compile it as a loadable module—which is a lot easier for tinkering with a driver.